# Detect if Serial1 and Serial2 are defined, at compile time

Tags: serial, c-preprocessor

I have my library that uses `Serial`, `Serial1` and `Serial2` to establish various logging scenarios. Library user would define the config at class constructor, using simple byte constants like 0, 1 and 2.

Problem is, `Serial1` and `Serial2` are not available in all board types. So when I compile my code (that compiles fine on Mega) on Uno, I get error 
`'Serial1' was not declared in this scope`.

So I figure I need to adjust my code with preprocessor directive like `#if defined`, in order to include some code only if Serial1 is defined. But it wouldn't work, because Serial1 is defined later, at compile-time. So what is the accepted way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if the SDK has particular hardware defines setup for things like a serial port.  Most look at the SDK's processor defines and use conditional compilation directives such as "#ifdef ARDUINO_AVR_UNO".

Comment: Also, I'm looking at the [ArduinoBoardManager at github source code](https://github.com/backupbrain/ArduinoBoardManager) and do not see where they define hardware like serial port on a per processor bases.  Maybe you could add that and re-use this code.  But I still think the easiest way about this is pick what serial port code you want to compile based on the processor type.  Look at the source code in this github project to see how they did this.

Comment: Why not make the constructor take an object reference of type `Serial` (or `HardwareSerial` or even `Print`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[HardwareSerial.h](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h) in Arduino AVR boards core defines HAVE_HWSERIALX

example

```
#ifndef HAVE_HWSERIAL1
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(6, 7); // RX, TX
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the approach used [here in the ArduinoBoardManager project at github](https://github.com/backupbrain/ArduinoBoardManager).  The file [ArduinoBoardManager.h](https://github.com/backupbrain/ArduinoBoardManager/blob/master/ArduinoBoardManager.h) uses conditional compiling to determine the correct code to compile based on processor type.  A similar approach can be used to asses if certain hardware peripherals such as serial ports were available based on processor type.

```
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) // uno, fi
  // Code compatible with an Arduino Uno
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  // Code compatible with an Arduino Mega
#endif
```

Comment: why do it, if HardwareSerial.h does it for you. and for example Uno Wifi has additional hw Serial1 (to connect onboard esp8266) even it is a 328p

Comment: Oh, I agree - I didn't know about the alternatives until posted here.  I just knew how the ArduinoBoardManager project was handling it.